# How to limit tensorflow_model_server to process one request at a time? Processing multiple requests causes it to crash

Tags: server, request, queue, grpc, tensorflow-serving

How do I limit tensorflow_model_server to process one request at a time? Processing multiple requests causes it to crash due to CPU and RAM usage. Ideally I want other requests to get queued behind and processed 1 by 1.

I've currently tried passing in the argument grpc.max_concurrent_streams=1 as part of the --grpc_channel_arguments under tensorflow_model_server but it doesn't seem to work.

I've considered using a process queue like Redis Queue/Celery but this isn't ideal since I am calling the inference from Tensorflow through an API and I don't want to have to continually ping the API to find out the status of the task, ideally i want it to block until I receive the response. Also I'm pretty sure this is what Celery is supposed to be used for.

I've also considered putting it behind something like HAProxy with 1 maximum connection but this seems like overkill and I'm not even sure how I should set it up, its a bit out of my depth.

Help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a great answer, but a couple of things you could *try*:

1. Try setting --tensorflow_session_parallelism to equal the # of tensorflow threads, such that a single request hogs all the tensorflow session threads and doesn't let any other requests use any threads.
2. Enable batching with max_batch_size=1 and num_batch_threads=1, which will give you serialized batches of size 1 each -- it's a degenerate form of "batching" that would give you the admission control you need.